# Question on jointly distributed uniform random variables (deriving density function)

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, uniform-distribution

I am looking at a simple example of choosing a point at random on a disk (circle) of radius $1$. The text book states simply:

$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}$ if $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Now, when thinking in terms of single variable integrals, I understand that to find the pdf of a uniform random variable $X \in [a,b]$ we simply have the pdf equal to $\frac{1}{b-a}$ and this function integrates to $1$ over the range $[a,b]$. I know a similar version is at work here in the multivariate case but can't as easily see the justification or how to set-up the double integral to integrate over the circle using the pdf $\frac{1}{\pi}$ to get $1$.

I assume that for any area $A$ we simply have $\frac{1}{A}$ as our pdf. Can someone give me the generic double integral that we would use for an arbitrary area $A$? I suppose for a square or rectangle it seems straightforward $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ would imply a double integral of the form$\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d}$ but for a circle or a more complex area I am a bit lost.

Can someone shine some light on ways to think about the multivariate case of deriving the pdf and also provide guidance on how to set-up the double integral that would integrate $\frac{1}{\pi}$ to $1$? I am having a hard time figuring out the limits of integration.

Comment: Hint: The disk of support has radius $r = 1$ and area $A = \pi r^2 = \pi,$ so for the volume beneath the uniform density $f(x,y) = c$ and above the disk to be unity, you must have $c = 1/\pi.$ Of course the volume can be expressed by the double integral of $f(x,y)$ over the disk, but now you already know the answer by geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate over a unit circle, $y$ should range from $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ while $x$ stays inside $[-1,1]$ (look at the circle to see this). This is a slightly annoying integral to do directly, but can be done using trig substitutions:

$$ \int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\dfrac{1}{\pi}dydx = 1$$

Otherwise, it'll be easier to convert to polar coordinates:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{\pi}rdrd\theta = 1$$